# LWJGL 2.9 - Pixel format not accelerated error out of the blue

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

So, while programming in Java and LWJGL I was working on a simple game for fun.
And everything worked, I could run the game, and play. But then I leave my computer alone for about 30 minutes and come back to run the game again, and I get the `Pixel format not accelerated` error. I don't know where it came from, but I assure you it worked earlier. I thought maybe restarting the engine and game to see if I could fix it again.

Here is my code after restarting:

`

```
package engine.dungeon.core;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

public class Window {

    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = 480;

    public Window() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! There was an update for my graphics card that I got after restarting my computer for a second time.

Answer (score 1):

A Pixel format not accelerated error has to do with your graphics card.

- Some video cards are too old, and should either be updated with drivers, or replaced.
- Some times GPU drivers could crash so a computer restart may solve your problem

Comment: But it was working fine about 30 minutes before I touched it again, so that is why I'm confused and I did restart the computer, and I got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the Nvidia driver 378.49. This driver is simply broken.
See for more detail:

- http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=6447.0
- http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=6439.msg34284#msg34284

or simply google "LWJGL Pixel format not accelerated" and you'll find hundreds of posts mostly from Minecraft users.